# CORS blocks jquery on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, cors

So I got to do a website for my mediaproduction course.

The task is to enfold a section by clicking on a button. But everytime I click on the button I get some CORS errors in the browser console. The strange thing is, it only happens in Chrome. Firefox works fine.[chrome console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/219uE.png)

Comment: You need to be running your page on a local server not from `file://` protocol in order to use ajax. There are browser extension workarounds but setting up local server is very easy

Comment: Are you on a Mac?

Comment: Is the button doing request on local resources or external? As it works in some browsers, I would guess charlietfl solved the mystery already. In that case, I would suggest running a local lightweight server (e.g.: http://livereload.com/) to really avoid any specific behavior while serving local files. If there are external requests, look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS to understand the issue better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below quote for MacOS and Windows:

> Chrome has a wonderful command line argument to disable web security. To start Chrome with web security disabled, run the following command:
>
> `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-web-security`
>
> If you’re using Windows, navigate to the path of your installation via a command prompt and run the following:
>
> `Chrome.exe --disable-web-security`

reference: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/08/bypass-cors-errors-testing-apis-locally/

Comment: Try to host file which has ajax in apache server on your machine so it can be opened with http://localhost/path to your html file inside htdocs or apache public folder which contains your file... I think it will solve your problem with chrome... Chrome 70 and above is too restricted even if we try to make a site with https on localhost